# How To Add Whatsup Share on product Page in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-page

How to add **whatsup** share link in magento2 Product page?

Comment: you can use this extension 
https://evincemage.com/whatsapp-share-magento2.html

Comment: Can This extension is compatible with magento2  @RakeshDonga magento 2.2.6

Comment: yes sure @hemalata

Comment: Hi @hemalata did u added the whatsapp extension

Answer (score 1):

Three steps:

1. Find Whatsapp Icon.
2. Copy Paste below code to any of yours PHTML file where you want whatsapp the share button.
3. Update the Whatsapp Icon Image Src

   ```
   <?php $urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
       $_currentUrl = $urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
   ?>    
   <a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo $_currentUrl?>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"><img src='WHATSAPP_ICON_IMG_SRC_HERE' /></a>
   ```

Comment: How can i send my EventObserver log message by whatsapp message? @Akhil

Comment: @zus Not sure what do you mean by Event Observer Log message. But in above answer instead <?php echo $_currentUrl?>you can add whatever message you want. This message only will be shared to whatsapp on click whatsapp Icon.

Comment: Hi @AkhilGupta i have added the above code in product page but the link is not working

Answer (score 0):

There are some extensions available for the whatsapp sharing with some advanced option you can check below free extension :

> https://evincemage.com/whatsapp-share-magento2.html
>
> https://www.milople.com/magento-extensions/whatsapp-share.html

Comment: How can i send my EventObserver log message by whatsapp message? @Amit

Comment: @zus, can you explain your problem little bit more?